# Renaming Span with Open Telemetry HTTP Instrumentation

Tags: typescript, open-telemetry

I am using the HTTP Instrumentation from `@opentelemetry/instrumentation-http`. In this your spans are automatically named something generic like `HTTP GET` OR `HTTP POST` and natively `span.updateName` doesn't actually rename the span when it is sent off. I have found a solution here (not exactly applicable to my issue but best I could find): https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-dotnet/issues/1277 and reworked it for typescript:

```js
class ActivityNameProcessor implements SpanProcessor {
  onStart(span: Span): void {
    // can't update name here as I don't know if its the span I want to rename
  }
  onEnd(span: Span): void {
    // can't update span here because I get an error
  }
  shutdown(): Promise<void> {
    return Promise.resolve();
  }

  forceFlush(): Promise<void> {
    return Promise.resolve();
  }
}
```

I can then add this to my provider like such:

```js
const provider = new NodeTracerProvider({
  resource,
});

provider.addSpanProcessor(new ActivityNameProcessor());

// I am also using a batch processor to send the traces off
provider.addSpanProcessor(
  new BatchSpanProcessor(traceExporter, {
    maxQueueSize: 1000,
    scheduledDelayMillis: 5000,
  })
);
```

The issue is when I attempt to change the name in `onEnd()` I get an error as the span is already in a complete state and the attribute cannot be changed. I can update the name in `onStart()` and it works as expected when the traces are view in New Relic, however, in that instance I don't have any context on the span and I do not want to rename all spans, only select ones with certain attributes.
Any help of sultions would be appreciated,
Thanks :)